# What is the value of this bad resistor?

Tags: resistors

[image]

Orange, white, gold, gold, black.      3.9 ohms?     Also what do you think is it's wattage?   8mm x 3mm     Thanks

Comment: Welcome! What length and diameter is it?

Comment: 8mm long, 3mm diameter.

Comment: 0.5 W rating most probably.

Comment: Value?   3.9 ohms?  The 2 gold bands confuse me....

Comment: First gold band is a 1/10 multiplier. Any good color code table will explain this.

Answer (score 1):

That's not just bad, it's naughty.

The value is 3.9Ω ±5% - 1W.

Could be 0.5W but since it's burned out, I think it's better to increase the wattage a little.

Comment: Also nobody specifies 5% resistors since 20-something years back. There's no reason not to use 1%.